# update gridview field without dataBind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

i have a gridview that show comments. i want that if a person likes a comment, press a like button and i increse the sum of likes , but i do not want to connect to database and bind. i want do that using ajax. how can i do that?
here is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdCommentsForLoginnedUser" 
                  runat="server" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Width="100%" 
                  OnRowCommand="grdCommentsForLoginnedUser_RowCommand"
                  ViewStateMode="Inherit">
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCommentID" runat="server"
                   Value='<%# Bind("CommentID") %>'/>              
              <table border="2" dir="rtl">
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #6699FF" width="200px">
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCommenterName"
                        runat="server"
                        NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("CommenterProfile") %>'
                        Text='<%# Bind("CommenterName") %>' />                     
                </td>
                <td width="700px">
                  <br />
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCommentText" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Bind("CommentText") %>' />
                  <br /> 
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="700px">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblPreviousAcceptOrNonAccept" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Bind("PersonPreviousAcceptOrNonAccept") %>' />
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnRemovePreviousAcceptOrNonAccept" 
                        runat="server"   
                        Text='<%# Bind("RemovePersonPreviousAcceptOrNonAccept") %>'
                        CommandName="RemovePreviousAcceptOrNonAccept" 
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                  <br />
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnUpRate" runat="server" Text="Like"
                        Visible='<%# Bind("isLikeAndUnlikeButtonVisible") %>'  
                        CommandName="LikeComment" 
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                  <br />sum of likes
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCommentLikes" runat="server"
                             Text='<%# Bind("CommentLikes") %>' />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a client side `onClick` javascript to each button. When clicked get the parent `td` tag and then `getElementById("lblCommentLikes")` to set the `.innerText` property of the `"lblCommentLikes"` `span`.

```
+(theTD.getElementById("lblCommentLikes").innerText)+=1;
```

or

```
+(theTD.getElementById("lblCommentLikes").innerText)-=1;
```

Tip: If you are using IE then press F12 to inspect the `DOM` of a running page